# Convert Matrix to RDD - Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a DenseMatrix of 8 x 252. And an array of column names 252. I want to convert this densematrix to RDD.

DenseMatrix:

```
2.00 3.00 ...
3.00 3.01 ...
```

Column Array: `Array("Column1","Column2",...)`

I want to convert the above to Dataframe as

```
Column1 Column2   ..
2.00    3.00      ..
3.00    4.00      ..
```

Could anyone help me in this?
**If not Dataframe, atleast an RDD**

Comment: `sc.parallelize(mat.rowIter.toSeq)` but point of having RDD with 8 rows eludes me :)

Comment: How do I convert it to DataFrame? I basically wants the result as in Dataframe so that it'll be easier to extract values based on column names.

Comment: `_.map(_.toArray).toDF` and `select` by index is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: I tried that with RDD[Vector] and also with RDD[Row] but I am getting.  
value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector]

I used sqlcontext and also imported implicits

Comment: Snippet I've shown should work in any recent (2.0+) Spark version. Add tuple wrapper if you use 1.x

Comment: If you could provide a code snippet would be really helpful!

Comment: `val vs: RDD[Vector] = ???; val ncol: Int = ???; val names: Seq[String] = ???; vs.map(v => Tuple1(v.toArray)).toDF("arr").select((0 until ncol).map(i => $"arr".getItem(i)): _*).toDF(names: _*)`